# CSS Flexbox - how to make a parent div the height of a nested child img

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, height

This may have been answered but I'm struggling to find it. I have a container with a slide-wrap that contains a slide with a hero img and footer. I want the hero img to fill the full width of the viewport (it is a long banner) but I want to keep the image's proportions and have the rest of the container change in height if the width of the viewport changes. I have to have all the nesting for the skas of the slide functionality.

Everything is working except for the height.

I've tried to do this using display:flex but I have to set a fixed height at the container level otherwise nothing shows up.

Is there a way to do this in css or will I have to use js?

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slide-wrap">
        <?php 
          
         //php to dynamically create the slides

            <!-- Individual slides -->
            <div class="slide">
              <img class="hero-img" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="">

              <!-- Hero showcase footer -->
              <div id="hero-footer">
                <a class="btn-secondary" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Press</a>
              </div>

            </div>

          <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="arrows">
        <div><i id="arrow-left" class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-2x" href="#"></i></div>
        <div><i id="arrow-right" class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-2x" href="#"></i></div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

and the css:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 750px;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.slide.current {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hero-img {
  width: 100%;
}

#hero-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: $text-color;
}

#hero-footer a {
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 200px;
}

.arrows {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

#arrow-left {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#arrow-right {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  z-index: 11;
}
```

Comment: have u tried bottom:0 and right:0 in .slide class to provide complete height and complete width ?

Comment: I've just tried that, and the container is still collapsed. In other words nothing is showing up.

Comment: Could you provide a code sample of what the PHP outputs?

Comment: I just noticed that you have an unclosed `<?php` tag on line 3 of your sample

Comment: Thanks Dan, it was correct in my code - just not in what I've posted here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking for an aspect ratio maintaining CSS solution.

Here is a solution in SCSS to create a 16x9 container:

```
[data-ar] {
    position: relative;
    &:before {content: ''; display: block;}
    > * {top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; position: absolute;}
}
[data-ar='16:9']:before {padding-top: 9 / 16 * 100%;}
```

Then apply the class as a wrapper to your image:

```
<div data-ar="16:9">
    <img class="hero-img" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="">
</div>
```

Simply change the variables to make any other arbitrary aspect ratio:

```
[data-ar='16:9']:before {padding-top: 9 / 16 * 100%;}
[data-ar='4:3']:before {padding-top: 3 / 4 * 100%;}
[data-ar='176:43']:before {padding-top: 43 / 176 * 100%;}
```

Comment: I've just tried this, the continued problem I have is that the parent container is still collapsed. The .container, .slide-wrap, .slide are all nested and therefore the img height is hidden. In the inspector I can see that the image has a height, but none of its parents do, so nothing is showing up.

Comment: Could you try wrapping `.slide-wrap` in the aspect ratio div? `<div data-ar="16:9"><div class="slide-wrap">...</div></div>` or possibly `<div class="slide-wrap" data-ar="16:9">`

Comment: I did try this and it also had no effect. In the end I went for a javascript option.